# hostname of connection source

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to know from which host I have connected?

```
host1> mysql -h10.10.10.10 -uroot -pPassWd
```

I connect to host2 from host1

How do I know from which host I am connected?

Update:

I do not want to know **TO which host** I am connected, but **FROM which host** I am connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answers that work via current_user() won't always work**. If the user can connect via a wildcard, it'll return something like `root@%` or `someuser@10.1.5.%`

`user()` returns the user as it's connected, while `current_user()` returns the user as it was defined. So you can get your hostname like this:

```
SELECT trim(mid(current_user(), position('@' in current_user())+1, 255))
```

The host that you are connecting to can be retrieved like this:

```
SELECT @@hostname
```

Comment: show processlist is showing the correct IP, but is there a variable for this like @@from_hostname

Comment: I want to "use" the connection_id and from_hostname and not just "show" it.

Comment: What you're looking for seems to be:     `select trim(mid(user(), position('@' in user())+1, 255))`. User() returns the user as it's acutally connected, while current_user() returns the user as it was defined.

Comment: @shantanuo: try `select user();` it will return from which host and bu which user you are connected.[AFAIK]

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select user();
```

or

```
select current_user();
```

It will result in user@host.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user

Answer (score 0):

Returns the current `MySQL user name and host name.`

```
mysql> select current_user();
    +------------------+
    | current_user()   |
    +------------------+
    | vector@localhost |
    +------------------+
    1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select @@hostname;
    +------------+
    | @@hostname |
    +------------+
    | nvc-10     |
    +------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```